# node.js - Use variables outside functions

Tags: node.js, function, variables

I'm new to node.js, and I'm struggling with functions and variables.

```
let shops = ['shop-one', 'shop-two']

function getShops(shops){
    shops.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        const shop = element        
    });
}

function getUrl(shop){
    console.log(shop)
}

getShops(shops)

getUrl(shop) // shop is not defined
```

How can I use variables from one function on the other function or outside the functions for further use?
Like in my example I would use the Shopname 'shop-one' from the forEach-Loop in function getShops to be used on the function getUrl or even outside any function.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you want to elaborate what requirement you want to implement? From the code, it's a bit hard to guess.

Comment: I want to get the shops from a .env file then build an array from the .env (SHOPS=shop-one,shop-two) with the shops after this I want to go through that array and load the specific JSON file for that shop and get some values from it to use on other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let shops = ['shop-one', 'shop-two'];
// An object to store urls that will look like
// {'shop-one': 'http://aurl4shop1.com', 'shop-two': 'http://aurl4shop2.com' }
let urls = {}; 
let json = [];

function getShops(shops){
    shops.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
        const shop = element;
        // The following line will set a property on the url object with the value of the url.  The property name is the shop name.
        url[shop] = getUrl(shop);        
    });
}

function getUrl(shop){
    console.log(shop);
}

shops.forEach(shop => json[shop] = fetchJson(shop);

// At this point the json object should look like this:
// { 'shop-one': { /* some json */ }, 'shop-two': /* some json */ }
```

Comment: Any explanation? 

What does url[show] = getUrl(shop); do? and why let urls = {};

Comment: Sorry - show was a a typo - should have been 'shop'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I think this won't fix my problem.
Isn't there a way to declare a variable in a function that can be used outside the function like in python? Maybe I'm thinking wrong... but I want to use the getUrl function to load the JSON File from the shop I get from the function getShops. 

Example: With the function getShops I get the array of shops, and the names, and then I want to load the shopname.json to find the url of the shop in the shopname.json. If I got the url I would use another function to pass that url in and use the url for further things.

Comment: "Isn't there a way to declare a variable in a function that can be used outside the function like in python?" No.  The function is a closure.  More on that here: https://medium.com/@prashantramnyc/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4